# Django ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, mysqlconnector

Возникла проблема , если нажать два раза на удаление товара из корзины появляется ошибка ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение. Так же и с добавление товара в корзину или изменением кол-ва. Подскажите как исправить.

```
class DeleteFomCartView(CartMixin,View):

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        product_slug=kwargs.get('slug')
        size= kwargs.get('size')
        product= Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        try:
            cart_product=CartProduct.objects.get(
            user=self.cart.owner,cart=self.cart,product=product,size=size
        )
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
            
        self.cart.products.remove(cart_product)
        cart_product.delete()
        recalc_cart(self.cart)
        messages.add_message(request,messages.INFO,'Товар Удален')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

```
[24/Jan/2021 10:41:34] "GET /remove-from-cart/probes2/XL/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55719)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
----------------------------------------
```